# jQuery - Switch between background picture and background video using a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I was searching and searching everywhere, but I couldn't find anything that would help me out with my question, so I'm seeking for help here.

Initially, I'd like to have a background video playing on my website, but whenever a certain checkbox is ticked, switch to a picture. When it's unticked, it should play the video again.

I'm not sure if this is possible with jQuery and if it isn't, please advise me on what language is capable of this. If possible, I'd like to have another checkbox which when ticked, mutes music, again if possible.

Thank you very much in advance for answers. If you need any more information, just ask :)

Comment: How are you playing the video? Youtube link? `<video>`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How is your video displayed on your page? You will need to show us some code if you want some help. HTML, CSS, Javascript.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, here's the work in progress url http://52.29.79.215/ . I'm playing the video off my Amazon S3 bucket and using Dreamweaver to build the site. CSS is also made by me. Sorry if there's any errors in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution you can try

```
<body style="background:your background definition">
<video style="display:block" video details> </video>
```

With a jquery that toggles the display between block and none, thus...

```
$('#checkboxToToggleVideo').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('#bgvid').css('display','none');
    } else {
       $('#bgvid').css('display','block');
    }
});
```

Refer the following http://jsfiddle.net/dLxacefw/2/

A modified jsfiddle along with a sample image
http://jsfiddle.net/dLxacefw/5/

Note that I have used img tag instead here, and hava z-index<0 to allow for remaining elements to appear above the background

Comment: Could you update the fiddle to reflect the change from video to picture with this pic? https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/thanksdfg.com/image/pre-finals.png

Comment: Thank you very much! It's just what I needed :D